# Unable to communitcate between two sibling containers

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, xunit

I have two projects, one is aspnet core API project and other is xUnit e2e project, both deployed in two different containers.

Once both containers are up and running, the e2e container tries to hit the APIs of the Web API project on url https://web-api-container:5010/. But the e2e project unable to hit the API project. It looks like the API project is not accessible with its hostname (http://web-api-container:5010/). I get following error in my cli:

> | Error Message: | System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : Connection
>   refused | ---- System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : Connection refused
>   | Stack Trace: | at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String
>   host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken) | at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1.get_Result() | at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) | at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1.get_Result()

Even if I try to access my Web API url (http://web-api-container:5010/) directly from my host machine browser, I get site cannot be reached error. But if I navigate to http://localhost:5010/ from my web browser, I am able to get the response from the API.

**./Source/WebAPI/Dockerfile:**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY Source/WebAPI/WebAPI.csproj Source/WebAPI/
COPY Tests/WebAPI.UnitTests/WebAPI.UnitTests.csproj Tests/WebAPI.UnitTests/

RUN dotnet restore Tests/WebAPI.UnitTests/WebAPI.UnitTests.csproj
RUN dotnet restore Source/WebAPI/WebAPI.csproj

COPY . .

WORKDIR /src/Tests/WebAPI.UnitTests/
RUN dotnet build && dotnet test -c Release /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=json /p:CoverletOutput=./TestResults/Coverage/


WORKDIR /src/Source/WebAPI
RUN dotnet build WebAPI.csproj -c Release -o /app



FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish WebAPI.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebAPI.dll"]
```

**./Tests/WebAPI.EndToEndTests/Dockerfile:**

```
#pull from microsoft/dotnet
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1.301-sdk AS build

WORKDIR /src

# copying
COPY Tests/WebAPI.EndToEndTests/WebAPI.EndToEndTests.csproj Tests/WebAPI.EndToEndTests/

#restore 
RUN dotnet restore Tests/WebAPI.EndToEndTests/WebAPI.EndToEndTests.csproj

#copy rest
COPY . .

#build
WORKDIR /src/Tests/WebAPI.EndToEndTests
RUN dotnet build
CMD ["sh", "-c", "sleep 1m && dotnet test --logger trx"]
```

**./docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  webapi:
    container_name: web-api-container
    image: web-api-image
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Source/WebAPI/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5010:80
      - 5001:443
    networks: 
      - my-network

  webapiendtoend:
    container_name: e2e-test-container
    image: Web-api-endtoend-test-image
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Tests/WebAPI.EndToEndTests/Dockerfile
    networks:  
      - my-network

  rabbitmq:
    container_name: rabbitmq-container
    image: "rabbitmq:3.7-management"
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
    tty: true
    networks:  
      - my-network
    volumes:
      - ./Source/WebAPI/RabbitMQConfig/rabbitmq.config:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config:ro
      - ./Source/WebAPI/RabbitMQConfig/definitions.json:/etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json:ro

networks:
  my-network:
```

**Tests\WebAPI.EndToEndTests\appsettings.json:**

```
{
  "MessageQueueApi": {
    "Url": "http://web-api-container:5010/"
  }
}
```

**./Tests/WebAPI.EndToEndTests/Test/BaseTest.cs:**

```
public class BaseTest : IDisposable
    {
        public BaseTest()
        {
            var appSettings = AppSettings.Current;
            var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate,
            };
            this.HttpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler)
            {
                BaseAddress = appSettings.MessageQueueApi.Url,

            };
            Console.WriteLine("<---API URL is --->" + appSettings.MessageQueueApi.Url);

            Console.WriteLine("---Base address");
            Console.WriteLine(this.HttpClient.BaseAddress);
        }

        public HttpClient HttpClient { get; set; }

        public List<string> AllValues { get; set; }

        public void Dispose() => this.HttpClient.Dispose();

        protected async Task GetAllValues()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("----in get all values---");
            var response  = await this.HttpClient.GetAsync("api/values");
            response.StatusCode.ShouldBe(HttpStatusCode.OK);         
        }


        protected Task<HttpResponseMessage> ClearCache() =>
            this.HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("cache/clear", string.Empty);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`5010` is the port exposed to the host machine. You can communicate using container's port within containers. Use port `80` instead of using `5010`.

```
http://web-api-container:80
```

this will do the job.